# Non-nullable instance field '_db' must be initialized. (Documentation)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm try do something here but getting an error

NotesDBWorker.dart

```
 class NotesDBWorker {
  NotesDBWorker._();
  static final NotesDBWorker db = NotesDBWorker._();
  Database _db;

  Future get database async {
    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    if (_db == null) {
      _db = await init();
    }

    return _db;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your variable to have a `null` state, you should declare it as nullable by adding a `?` after the name of the type. Using `late` will result in a runtime `LateInitializationError`.

```dart
class NotesDBWorker {
  NotesDBWorker._();
  static final NotesDBWorker db = NotesDBWorker._();
  Database? _db;

  Future get database async {
    if (_db == null) {
      _db = await init();
    }

    return _db;
  }
}
```

You should generally also not be suppressing analyzer warnings. They are there for a reason.